# How to get focus() works after onMouseDown event?

Tags: javascript

After MouseDown event the focus must be redirected to another element, but it persists in current element. How to get it works?

```js
function setFocus() {
  alert('MouseDown');
  document.getElementById("but").focus();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onmousedown="setFocus()">Press</button>
<button id="but" type="button">Test</button>
```

Is it awaiting for MouseUp event? How to clear it then?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `preventDefault()`. It blocks the default onmousedown event

```js
function setFocus(e) {
  alert('MouseDown');
  e.preventDefault()
  document.getElementById("but").focus();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onmousedown="setFocus(event)">Press</button>
<button id="but" type="button">Test</button>
```